# SQL Query to retrieve last transactional date from the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

This is my problem. I want to write a query to retrieve the last transactional date less than a selected date from the database. As it stands but it will only work when the user selects the present date. It fails when the user selects previous date. This is my query.

```
Select max(Date_Recorded) as LastStockDate
from Importer_Reconciliation
where importer=@Importer and product=@Product
```

`@Importer` and `@Product` are parameters which are been passed to the query.

Comment: Please use to two brackets to format ur codes properly.

Comment: can you please post your code segment: does the fields `importer` and `product` are `date and Time` fields?

Comment: When you say less than the selected date, where is the selected date then ? which of the parameters is the selected date?

Comment: In what way does it fail? Error? unexpected output? How does the user select the date? In an application? If so please explain further

Answer (score 0):

Where is the selected date ? which of the parameters represent the selected date ? It seems to me your query is quite ok. You just have t add the selected date parameter

```
Select max(Date_Recorded) as LastStockDate
from Importer_Reconciliation
where importer=@Importer and product=@Product and DateRecorded < @selectedDate
```

Comment: Thanks to all. All the suggestions are meaningful and they helped in resolving the issue. I was able to sought it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(recorded_date) as 
LastStockDate
from Importer_Reconciliation
where importer=@Importer and product=@Product and recorded_Date<THE_DATE_YOU_WANT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    recorded_date AS LastStockDate
FROM
    Importer_Reconciliation
WHERE
    importer = @Importer
    AND product = @Product
    AND recorded_Date < Required_Date
    ORDER BY recorded_Date desc;
```